# How can I hide table 'colSpan' column header with values?

Tags: jquery

I've a table with lots of columns. The table do not have id or name and hr tag for header. The header coloumns have set with 'colSpan' value. How can I hide table 'colSpan' column header with values?

Comment: Could you add the html code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

The header line should be the first line and thus the first child element of your table. So you can select it by doing `$("table tr:first-child")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('td[colspan=2]').hide();
```

or something similar
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/